# Calculating flow panel width based on its contents

Tags: delphi, resize, flowpanel

I am dynamically populating frames into flow panels (as part of a horizontally oriented VCL Metropolis app). I need to resize each group's flow panel to fit all its items horizontally. I have a very simple formula which does the trick sometimes, but not all the time - specifically when adding an odd number of items. The flow panel's `FlowStyle` is set to `fsTopBottomLeftRight` and fits 2 frames vertically.

For example, adding 7 items automatically detects the correct width (4 items across). But adding 5 items does not detect the correct width (supposed to be 3 across but winds up detecting 2 across).

How can I make it correctly calculate the width for each group?

Here's the procedure that populates the items into each item group (some irrelevant stuff removed):

```
procedure TSplitForm.LoadScreen;
const
  FRAME_WIDTH = 170;    //Width of each frame
  FRAME_HEIGHT = 250;   //Height of each frame
  FRAME_MARGIN = 30;    //Margin to right of each group
  FRAME_VERT_COUNT = 2; //Number of frames vertically stacked
var
  CurGroup: TFlowPanel; //Flow panel currently being populated
  procedure ResizeGroup(FP: TFlowPanel);
  var
    Count, CountHalf, NewWidth, I: Integer;
  begin
    //Resize the specific flow panel's width to fit all items
    Count:= FP.ComponentCount;
    NewWidth:= FRAME_WIDTH + FRAME_MARGIN;  //Default width if no items
    if Count > 0 then begin
      //THIS IS WHERE MY CALCULATIONS DO NOT WORK
      CountHalf:= Round(Count / FRAME_VERT_COUNT);
      NewWidth:= (CountHalf * FRAME_WIDTH) + FRAME_MARGIN;
    end;
    if FP.Parent.Width <> NewWidth then
      FP.Parent.Width:= NewWidth;
    //Resize main flow panel's width to fit all contained group panels
    //(automatically extends within scroll box to extend scrollbar)
    Count:= TFlowPanel(FP.Parent.Parent).ControlCount;
    NewWidth:= 0;
    for I := 0 to Count-1 do begin
      NewWidth:= NewWidth + FP.Parent.Parent.Controls[I].Width;
    end;
    NewWidth:= NewWidth + FRAME_MARGIN;
    if FP.Parent.Parent.Width <> NewWidth then
      FP.Parent.Parent.Width:= NewWidth;
  end;
  procedure Add(const Name, Title, Subtitle: String);
  var
    Frame: TfrmItemFrame;
  begin
    Frame:= AddItemFrame(CurGroup, Name); //Create panel, set parent and name
    Frame.OnClick:= ItemClick;
    Frame.Title:= Title;
    Frame.Subtitle:= Subtitle;
    ResizeGroup(CurGroup);
  end;
begin
  CurGroup:= fpMainGroup;
  Add('boxMainItem1', 'Item 1', 'This is item 1');
  Add('boxMainItem2', 'Item 2', 'This is item 2');
  Add('boxMainItem3', 'Item 3', 'This is item 3');
  Add('boxMainItem4', 'Item 4', 'This is item 4');
  Add('boxMainItem5', 'Item 5', 'This is item 5');

  CurGroup:= fpInventoryGroup;
  Add('boxInventItem1', 'Item 1', 'This is item 1');
  Add('boxInventItem2', 'Item 2', 'This is item 2');
  Add('boxInventItem3', 'Item 3', 'This is item 3');
  Add('boxInventItem4', 'Item 4', 'This is item 4');
  Add('boxInventItem5', 'Item 5', 'This is item 5');
  Add('boxInventItem6', 'Item 6', 'This is item 6');
  Add('boxInventItem7', 'Item 7', 'This is item 7');
end;
```

This is a screenshot of what that code is producing:

[image: Item width screenshot]

As you can see, the first group with 5 items is hiding the 5th item, but the second group with 7 items is showing all 7 just fine.

The structure of parent/child relationships is like so (with flow panels in question bold):

- SplitForm: TSplitForm (main form)

  - ScrollBox2: TScrollBox (container of main flow panel)

    - fpMain: TFlowPanel (container of all group panels)

      - pMainGroup: TPanel (container of flow panel and title panel)

        - **fpMainGroup**: TFlowPanel (container of item frames)
        - pMainGroupTitle: TPanel (title at top of group)
      - pInventoryGroup: TPanel (container of flow panel and title panel)

        - **fpInventoryGroup**: TFlowPanel (container of item frames)
        - pInventoryGroupTitle: TPanel (title at top of group)
      - (other panels for more groups)

I tried using each flow panel's `AutoSize` property, but it didn't acknowledge the heights (2 up) and made things even worse. I basically just need to properly detect the total number of columns within these flow panels.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That did the trick perfectly :-)

Comment: However, if you ever want to use more than 2 rows what you need is Ceil.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, I was thinking about that. For now, I'll support 2 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Round(Count / FRAME_VERT_COUNT);
```

Here `FRAME_VERT_COUNT` is `2`. When `Count` is `5` your expression becomes

```
Rount(2.5);
```

The default rounding mode is bankers rounding and this evaluates to `2`. When `Count` is `7` the expression is

```
Round(3.5);
```

Bankers rounding means this is `4`.

You could do what Sertac suggests and use `ceil`. However, I would simply avoid floating point altogether. It is just not needed and as a general rule, integer arithmetic is always to be preferred if it is viable. Your expression should be

```
(Count + FRAME_VERT_COUNT - 1) div FRAME_VERT_COUNT
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a partial tile, so when you're calculating how many columns are needed you want the nearest (equal or greater) integer.

In the default rounding mode, `Round(7/2)` is '4'. That's fine. However `Round(5/2)` is '2'. [That's because](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.SetRoundMode)

> With the default rounding mode (rmNearest), if X is exactly halfway
>   between two whole numbers, the result is always the even number.

With only two rows, rounding up can be a solution (division is always a whole number or a number exactly in between two whole numbers). For a general solution, better use `Ceil`.